# finding the max per id and creating a new column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

So, I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
id, counts
1, 20
1, 21
1,15
1, 24
2,12
2,42
2,9
3,43
...

id, counts, label
1, 20, 0
1, 21, 0
1,15, 0
1, 24, 1 # because 24 is the highest count for id 1
2,12, 0
2,42, 1 # because 42 is the highest count for id 2
2,9, 0
3,43, 
...
```

How do i do this in using pandas

Comment: @NickBull: not sure i understand.. swapped.. where?

Comment: Have you tried `groupby`? More generally, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
df['label'] = 0
df['label'].iloc[df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: x['counts'].argmax()).values] = 1
```

But it is so ugly! And does not follow good coding practices... I'll try to improve it.

---

If you like the below line, upvote [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38862031/3765319) (Merlin's answer to this question) to say thanks.

```
df['label'] = np.where(df.index.isin((df.groupby('id')['counts'].idxmax())), 1, 0)
```

IMHO, you should use Merlin's answer to solve this problem. Mine is not good coding practice and will scale poorly compared to Merlin's

Comment: I got it down to one line. :) Is it faster at scale?

Comment: No idea!!! Nice answer. I was trying with `np.where`, but not quite the way you did. Also, I would prefer your answer, better coding practice. I guess it would scale with the number of group sizes, although the size of each group would not have that huge an effect. (`.argmax` should scale well, only the `.apply` is a loop.)

Answer (score 3):

```
maxes = df.groupby('id').counts.max().rename('Max').reset_index()
df1 = df.merge(maxes, how='left')
df['Max'] = (df1.counts == df1.Max) * 1
df
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 df["label"] =  np.where( df.index.isin((df2.groupby("id")["counts"].idxmax())),1,0)

   id  counts  label
0   1      20      0
1   1      21      0
2   1      15      0
3   1      24      1
4   2      12      0
5   2      42      1
6   2       9      0
7   3      43      1
```

​